# I am looking for a JavaScript IRC client

Tags: javascript, irc

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jisirc/ is exactly what I need, only problem is it has multiple ActiveX dependencies and that will not do. Does anyone know of any similar projects which are more portable?

Answer (score 7):

You will have to have dependencies to an external application in order to open a socket towards the IRC server.

- It can be dependent on the browser architecture (ActiveX controls, Mozilla based, ...)
- Dependent on a java applet (in this case the irc server should be run on the same host the javascript originates from (unless you go towards signed applets))
- The "real" IRC client is running on server-side, and the script is only used to communicate with that client.

In DmitryK's list you will find an example for each.

Comment: Both mibbit and loq depend on flash or applet and I cannot use those with YUI Tabview apparently. And chatzilla is just what I need, but it won't work in IE6!

I guess I am going to do something similar to your third bullet point, using only javascript,html,css on the client side.

Answer (score 4):

- http://ajaxian.com/archives/mibbit-ajax-based-irc-client
- http://www.mozilla.org/projects/rt-messaging/chatzilla/
- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-5374.html

Comment: I tried mibbit but I don't want to have to depend on the Mibbit Service. Unfortunately I can't use Applets or Flash irc client in the YUI TabView without either reinitializing each time I change tabs. I have yet to find a solution for this.

I suppose I will take an approach like Zed's third bullet point and continuously poll the server for updates,although I was hoping to have the clients connect to the irc server directly.

Comment: @SeanA.O.Harney: see the Subway IRC client